# What is the downside of using OOP approach on JavaScript and React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I was creating some kind of base system for internal project, I was implementing a custom form system using OOP approach as I am using TypeScript.

```
class Form extends React.Component {}

abstract class FormElement extends React.Component<{validations?:ValidationLogic[]}> {
   validate();
   setData();
   setValidation();
}

class FormText extends FormElement {}
```

Referring to these: https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/how-to-use-classes-and-sleep-at-night-9af8de78ccb4

I want to know, is the downside of using class is purely subjective, or there is an objective point of view, if there's performance issue, I would be happy to see the data.

Thanks

Comment: OOP is *one* of programming *paradigms*. It could have pros and cons just as any other programming paradigm, e.g. such as functional paradigm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fine to do OO with React, and have the benefits as @sxzhao points out.

However, avoid using OO as a mechanism to reuse functions, or add more "features" to a React component such as extra logic.

It would be best to keep them separate from your React Components.

Your logic would be best to be handled in other places, such as using Redux, Mobx, or any other means.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. The reason I am using OO is to enforce user to extend from the abstract base class that provides basic implementation (e.g. in this case, setData, setValidation, and validate is provided by the abstract base class as it is tightly coupled with the Form component, and I don't see why i should move the logic that is tightly coupled to the component in other places). Is this a bad design in React, is there any metrics on why its bad?

Comment: The main idea is to separate UI rendering/logic from business logic. Mixing business logic in UI layer creates unnecessary coupling.

Answer (score 2):

When you create React components with the class syntax you will have access to the React's life cycle methods. You can read more about them [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html). Also if your component need to access to `this`, set state, or set `ref` you should use a class component.

Comment: Hi @sxzhao, thank you for your answer. I am OK with extending from React.Component, however, the article I referenced is talking about it is not OK to extend other than React.Component, in the example above, FormText is extending from abstract class FormElement as FormText is indeed a FormElement with different user interface. Is there any data on why its bad?